# jQuery hide() div until fully loaded

Tags: jquery, css, show-hide

I'm using tabbed featured post for my blog. How to implement the `div#latest-featured` will `hide()` then `show()` it back after content fully loaded?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<ul class="tabs">
  <li><a href="#f1">Title 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#f2">Title 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="latest-featured">
  <div id="f1" class="tab_content">
    <p>Content for title 1</p>
    <p>Why I want to hide the #latest-featured because.. when had image @ script here.. the tab_content will collapse all and break my design</p>
  </div>
  <div id="f2" class="tab_content">
    <p>Content for title 1</p>
    <p>Why I want to hide the #latest-featured because.. when had image @ script here.. the tab_content will collapse all and break my design</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example I have a div with id **`#latest-featured`** and I want hide it until the content is fully loaded, and then show it back after everything is loaded.

How to implement to the current code above.

Comment: Where do you want to use `#latest-featured`? I can't see any clue in your code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably best to do something like this:

```
<div id="latest-features" style="display:none;"></div>

$(function() {
    // do work
    $("div#latest-featured").show();
}
```

Its usually not a good idea to hide anything by default but this will meet your requirement.

Comment: the issue is if something messes up with your javascript or the browser doesn't support js that item will never be shown.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to show once loaded declare the CSS `display: none` for that div, and then call `$('div#latest-featured').show();` in your $(document).ready function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to show once loaded declare the CSS display: none for that div, and then call `$('div#latest-featured').show();` in your `$(document).ready` function.

Robert answered it best I would vote on it but can't yet...looked for this solution for hours and this was the best I have found...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the div to display:none until you have loaded the data, then remove the display:none ... there's lots of ways to do what I just mentioned btw (for instance, jQuery .toggle(true) )