# Executing jquery statements sequentially

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a Ruby on Rails app with some jquery to render partials asynchroneously. So first I want to change to active state of the tabs, then clear the tab pages and then load the partial:

```
  $('#availability').addClass('active');
  $('#overview').removeClass('active');
  $('#availabilityTab').addClass('active').addClass('in');
  $('#overviewTab').removeClass('active').removeClass('in');
  $("#availabilityTab").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'availability')) %>");
```

This works fine, however when I click the tab to trigger this, I expect to see a blank tabpage first and the the loaded data. What happens is when the tab is clicked, nothing seems to happen and then after 3 seconds the partials shows up. This is because the database call takes a while (needs to be optimized :-) ). This is confusing for the user, I rather want to see an empty tab page first. How can I do this?

Update: This is how the controller action looks like:

```
  def index
    @customers = Customer.order(:name)
    @target = params[:target] unless params[:target].blank?

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

And this is `index.js.erb`:

```
<% if @target == "overview" -%>
  $('#availability').removeClass('active');
  $('#overview').addClass('active');
  $('#overviewTab').addClass('active').addClass('in');
  $('#availabilityTab').removeClass('active').removeClass('in');
  $("#overviewTab").empty().html("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'overview')) %>");
<% elsif @target == "availability" -%>
  $('#availability').addClass('active');
  $('#overview').removeClass('active');
  $('#availabilityTab').addClass('active').addClass('in');
  $('#overviewTab').removeClass('active').removeClass('in');
  $("#availabilityTab").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'availability')) %>");
<% end %>
```

Comment: maybe try hide the element until fully load? check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452226/jquery-hide-div-until-fully-loaded

Comment: Maybe it's not visible until ou put content in it? Then you should set fixed width and height for tab

Comment: You're using `async: false` right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that you're using `async: false` in Ajax (this freezes the browser until the request completes)

Even if this is not the case, your effects are dependent on your db call, which is why you're experiencing the lag. To fix this, you either need to reconfigure your system to work *around* Ajax, or you need to trigger your effects as naturally as possible (I.E in the backend after the db call has been processed)

Here are two ways to look at it:

---

**Ajax Callbacks**

[wait for a jquery ajax callback from calling function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576176/wait-for-a-jquery-ajax-callback-from-calling-function)

We successfully use Ajax Callbacks to load partials in one of our production apps, here's how we do it:

```
 //app/assets/application.js
 $(".your_element").on("click", function() {
     fetch_modal("link", function(data){
         //success
     , function(data) {
         //error
     });
 });

 //Ajax
 function fetch_modal(link, success, error) {
   $.ajax({
      url: link,
      success: function(data) { success(data); },
      error: function(data)   { error(data); }
   });
 }
```

This will not freeze the browser, and works synchronously

I have a script which calls partials through Ajax using this technique if you'd like the link. I have been meaning to publish it

---

**Processing *After* The DB Call**

One reason you're seeing these problems if you're calling the JS after the event, not the result

To remedy this, I'd look at putting the "effect" code after the JS has been processed, like this:

```
#app/controllers/example_controller.rb
def example
    @example = Example.find(1)

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
        format.js 
    end
end

#app/views/example/example.js.erb
# Only fires after the DB call
$('#availability').addClass('active');
$('#overview').removeClass('active');
$('#availabilityTab').addClass('active').addClass('in');
$('#overviewTab').removeClass('active').removeClass('in');
$("#availabilityTab").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'availability')) %>");
```

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer! I do like the second solution, but do'n really get what you mean with "# Only fires after the DB call". It seems to me that the lines of jquery code is exactly the same as mine? I have updated my question with more information.

Comment: Hey John - I meant that it only fires after Rails has performed it's query, not when you've performed an event in JS. The different is that after the query will mean your app will show a "loading" icon for as long as the query is performed, and then the different classes are applied